# Change datePicker lines and font color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, customization, uidatepicker

Anyone know how change lines and font color of UIDatePicker and avoid using private Apple api?
I found this, but it the very dirty solution:

```
        datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")

        for subview in self.datePicker.subviews {

            if subview.frame.height <= 5 {

                subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                subview.tintColor = UIColor.white
                subview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                subview.layer.borderWidth = 0.5            }
        }

        if let pickerView = self.datePicker.subviews.first {

            for subview in pickerView.subviews {

                if subview.frame.height <= 5 {

                    subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                    subview.tintColor = UIColor.white
                    subview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                    subview.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
                }
            }
            self.datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

[image]

**OR by code:**

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.red, forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

Answer (score 0):

For change color of selected rectangle of `DatePickerView` you can do this:

```
datePicker.subviews[0].subviews[1].layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor //any color you want
datePicker.subviews[0].subviews[1].layer.borderWidth = 1
datePicker.subviews[0].subviews[2].layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor //any color you want
datePicker.subviews[0].subviews[2].layer.borderWidth = 1
```

The `subviews[1]` is the **upper** border, and the `subviews[2]` is the **below** border.
Also you should set `borderWidth` to make it visible

And for setting color of texts in whole `DatePicker` you can do this:

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "textColor")
```